# Joint PDF in a circle area.

Tags: probability, continuity, random-variables

I don't understand how can I solve this. My only guess it's that it's related with the probability of the circle area of c.

The coordinates X and Y of a point are independent zero mean normal
random variables with common variance $\sigma^2$ (Given that the point is at a distance of at least c from the origin. Find the conditional joint PDF of X and Y).

Comment: You will need to find $\mathbb{P}(X^2+Y^2 \ge c^2)$. You could use the chi-squared distribution

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independant, with pdf $f_X$ and $f_Y$, how do you write their joint pdf $f_{XY}$ ? You will end up with an expression in $x^2+y^2$ that invites you to switch to polar coordinates... @Henry I don't think Manuel will need to use the chi-square dist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$f_X(x)={1\over\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp{-x^2\over 2\sigma^2}$$
and similarly for $f_Y(y)$. Since $X$ and $Y$ are assumed independent
you then can write
$$f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)={1\over2\pi\sigma^2}\exp{-(x^2+y^2)\over 2\sigma^2}\ .$$If outcomes $(x,y)$ with $x^2+y^2<c^2$ are discarded you need the probability
$$P_{\geq c}:=\int_{x^2+y^2\geq c^2}f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)\>{\rm d}(x,y)={1\over2\pi\sigma^2}\int_c^\infty \exp{-r^2\over 2\sigma^2}\>2\pi r\>dr\ .$$
The conditional density is then given by
$$f(x,y)=\cases{0\qquad&$(x^2+y^2<c^2),$ \cr {\displaystyle{1\over P_{\geq c}}f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)}\qquad &$(x^2+y^2\geq c^2).$ \cr}$$

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Christian Blatter, can you explain how you wrote the conditional density function. If I have to write the conditional joint density given an event A, i would approach from the Joint Distribution Function as $F_{X,Y|A} (x,y) = P(X \leq x \cap Y \leq y |A) = \dfrac {P(X \leq x \cap Y \leq y \cap A)}{P(A)}$. Then $ f_{X,Y} (x,y) = \frac {\partial ^2}{\partial x \partial y} F_{ X,Y|A} (x,y)$

Comment: @Narendra: I restricted the known $f_{(X,Y)}$ to $x^2+y^2\geq c^2$ and divided by $P_{\geq c}$ in order to make sure that the desired $f$ has integral $1$ overall.